# Correlation coefficient with standard deviation

Tags: correlation, variance, standard-deviation, kurtosis

I quite often find myself testing hypotheses in which the standard deviation of one (Normally distributed) variable is linked to (the mean of) another variable. I would like to be able to express the strength of this association by means of an index between [-1, 1], similar in spirit to a correlation coefficient. I feel like I can't be the first one with this problem, so my first question is: does something like this exist? My second question is whether something I've come up with myself seems reasonable.

To express the problem more precisely, let $Z$ be a normally distributed variable:
$$
Z \sim N\left(0,\sigma^2\right)
$$
where the standard deviation $\sigma$ is a linear function of some other variables:
$$
\sigma=X\beta+\varepsilon
$$
where $X=\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_p\}$ is a set of predictor variables, and $\beta$ is a vector of linear coefficients on these predictors. So compared to the familiar linear model, the difference is that we now have a linear prediction for the second, rather than the first moment of the distribution of $Z$.

Given some observations of $Z$ and $X$, we can find the maximum likelihood estimate of $\beta$, which we'll denote $\hat{\beta}$. Now the question is, how much of the 'variance in variance' of $Z$ is explained by this linear model? This leads me to the idea of using kurtosis. That is, because $Z$ is distributed as a mixture of Normals with different SDs and a common mean, it will be leptokurtic and thus have excess kurtosis w.r.t. a Normal distribution with constant variance. However, if we divided each observation of $Z$ by its SD (i.e. $\dot{Z_i}=\frac{Z_i}{\sigma_i}$, where $\sigma_i=X_i\beta$), we should be able to reduce its kurtosis (to the point where, if the changes in variance of $Z$ are perfectly predicted by our fitted model, we should be able to get rid of 100% of the excess kurtosis).

So the index I'm proposing (analogous to $R^2$) is:
$$
\xi^2 = 1 - \frac{\left|\text{Kurt}[Z/\hat{\sigma}]-3\right|}{\text{Kurt}[Z]-3}
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}=X\hat{\beta}$. If our model explains no "variance in variance" at all, then the kurtosis should be just as high after we transform $Z$ as before, in which case $\xi^2=0$. If we managed to explain away all the changes in variance, then ${Z}/{\hat{\sigma}}$ should be perfectly Normally distributed (with kurtosis of 3), and thus $\xi^2=1$.

Does that seem reasonable? Did I just re-invent the wheel (or a dumb version of a wheel)?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to go the route of just modeling SD directly, as you do with the equation you present for sigma? I'm not sure I see the need to move to your kurtosis approach.

Comment: That would work fine for hypothesis testing (e.g. likelihood test of the full model (with all $\beta$'s active) vs. a reduced one), and is in fact what I have been doing. However, what I'm aiming at here is a measure of the strength of the association between $X$ and the SD of $Z$. Similar to how you can do hypothesis tests in a regression model, but it's also informative to examine the (partial) correlation coefficients on your regressors.

Comment: What is the intended meaning of the "association_index" that should range between [-1,+1] ? The way I read this you have a normal distribution centered at zero. Its width can be described by a linear function of some other variables. This is a standard parameter estimation setup: you have a model and you have some data. Why make it overly complicated, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'd like this index to be similar in spirit to a correlation coefficient. A correlation coefficient also isn't really "necessary", for the same reasons you mention. You have your linear model, and you have some data, so why go to the trouble? But correlation coefficients are still nice because they tell us something about the strength of a particular relationship, which is harder to glean from other statistics. Here, I want the same thing, only not for the dependence of Y on X but for the dependence of SD(Y) on X.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get how that would be useful. I share the concern about a correlation index (although I'm biased towards always using the actual covariance). But in that case it is an indicator of linear dependence; so for it to make sense one always needs to check the "linearity" of the data. In your case the only similarity rests in the linearity of the description. From what I understand you would like to quantify the dependence of sigma to the linear term; so something like $$\partial \sigma/\partial \beta$$